# search text march Entire text

Tags: javascript, html, css

developers. I need help. I have given below the code. when I type anything in the search box typed value matches the beginning of a list item. But I want when I type anything in the search box typed value to match any part of the search item and the text color will be red. I try so many times to do it.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  // find all `li` > a elements
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('ul#myUL li a');
      // iterate through all elements; re-hide & remove className from each.
      col.forEach(n=>{
      
        n.parentNode.style.display='none';
        n.classList.remove('bold');
        
        // if the typed value matches the beginning of a list item; display the text & assign Bold className
        if( this.value.length > 0 && this.value.trim()!='' && n.textContent.toLowerCase().startsWith( this.value.toLowerCase() ) ){
        
          n.parentNode.style.display='block';
          // make the whole word bold
          //n.classList.add('bold');
          
          // make the matched portion bold
          n.innerHTML = `<span class="bold">${this.value}</span>` + n.textContent.substr(this.value.length)
        }
      });
}



document.querySelector('input[name="search"]').addEventListener('keyup',myFunction);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#myUL li{
  display:none;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.bold{font-weight:bold;color:red
```

```html
<input name='search' type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `includes()` instead of `startsWith()`. To display the found text, you need to display the text before as well as the text after.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  // find all `li` > a elements
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('ul#myUL li a');
      // iterate through all elements; re-hide & remove className from each.
      col.forEach(n=>{
      
        n.parentNode.style.display='none';
        n.classList.remove('bold');
        
        // if the typed value matches the beginning of a list item; display the text & assign Bold className
        if( this.value.length > 0 && this.value.trim()!='' && n.textContent.toLowerCase().includes( this.value.toLowerCase() ) ){
        
          n.parentNode.style.display='block';
          // make the whole word bold
          //n.classList.add('bold');
          
          // make the matched portion bold
          n.innerHTML = n.textContent.substr(0,n.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.value.toLowerCase()))+`<span class="bold">${this.value}</span>` + n.textContent.substr(n.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.value.toLowerCase())+this.value.length)
        }
      });
}



document.querySelector('input[name="search"]').addEventListener('keyup',myFunction);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#myUL li{
  display:none;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.bold{font-weight:bold;color:red
```

```html
<input name='search' type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The code applied to highlight the searched query can be much more concise by doing the following ```n.textContent.replace(this.value, `<span style="color: red;">${this.value}</span>`)```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript there is a string method `includes()` which returns true if the substring is present in a specific string and returns false if not.

The below code will list only those items that contains the query entered by the user and highlight where there search query is present in that list item

```js
  function myFunction(e) {
    // find all `li` > a elements
    let col = document.querySelectorAll('ul#myUL li a');
    // iterate through all elements; re-hide & remove className from each.
    col.forEach(n => {

      n.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
      n.classList.remove('bold');

      // if the typed value matches the content of a list item; display the text & assign Bold className
      if (n.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
        console.log(n.textContent)
        n.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
        
        n.innerHTML = `${n.textContent.replace(this.value, `<span style="color: red;">${this.value}</span>`)}`
      }
    });
  }



  document.querySelector('input[name="search"]').addEventListener('keyup', myFunction);
```